# Installing vista on system with windows 7 installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, boot-manager

I have various versions Windows 7 installed on my test machine. I want to do the testing for windows vista.

I am just worried, if I install Vista and its earlier version of windows os, if it will it overwrite the boot manager? If no then great and if yes then how can I install Vista with proper boot manager entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed Vista on system with windows 7. It did not overwrite it.Thank God!

Comment: @Kalamane: The system requires two days before a self-answer could be accepted, this is one of the ways to prevent a lot of trivial problems from being posted an answered.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option running it in VM with something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) seems just the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 7 is your primary operating system you can all use the [Windows Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) which is a free addin for some versions of windows (Pro and higher I think)